# Browser compatility issue in firefox

Tags: firefox, web-testing

The following site ie(http://test.cancer.org.in/)  does not looks properly in firefox but it looks proper in IE(internet explorer) and the error it displays is :
The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.
resource://ftdownloader3-at-ftdownloader-dot-com/api-utils/lib/loader.js -> resource://ftdownloader3-at-ftdownloader-dot-com/api-utils/lib/sandbox.js -> resource://ftdownloader3-at-ftdownloader-dot-com/api-utils/lib/content/content-proxy.js
Line 13

Comment: so what should i do in order to remove the error

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the plugin error, you should contact the people that create the plugin, they're the only ones that can help you there. But that issue is unrelated to the display issues you're having.

Concerning your site, the fact that it looks horrible in both IE10 and Firefox, but OK in IE8 is because the styles don't get applied. What I know is that if your server is misconfigured and transmits css files with a content-type other than text/css, this will cause issues in Firefox when using xhtml doctype - it won't use the css files that way. You should reconfigure your webserver to send text/css for css files and application/javascript for js files.